# Create new column by combining the strings in three other columns

Tags: linux, awk

So, my file looks like:

```
First,Middle,Last,Prefix,Address,Address2,City,State,Zip
JOSHUA,D,EVOLA,MR,553 KIRKPATRICK RD,"",ENNIS,TX,75119
NICHOLAS,,HUDSON,MR,24 DWIGHT ST,APT 38,AGAWAM,MA,01001
```

I want to add a column (at column 0) which will be First+Middle+Last+7766.

(Note: Middle is empty in some of the records/rows.)

So, the result which I am looking for is:

```
JOSHUADEVOLA7766,JOSHUA,D,EVOLA,MR,553 KIRKPATRICK RD,"",ENNIS,TX,75119
NICHOLASHUDSON7766,NICHOLAS,,HUDSON,MR,24 DWIGHT ST,APT 38,AGAWAM,MA,01001
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1 $2 $3 7766, $0}' file
```

Comment: I am really a noob when it comes to linux. Assuming the input file name is 2.txt and I want to save it to a new file, say 3.txt What command should I run?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1 $2 $3 7766, $0}' 2.txt > 3.txt`